# create session variables in ajax success

Tags: javascript, ajax

When I logging to the system send username and password to the server and get response. then I need to make session variables from response data,  here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loginData() {

        var loginObject = {
            username: $("#username").val(),
            password: $("#password").val(),
        };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://enh-cis.cloudapp.net/e.cloud/api/UserLogin/GetUserLoginDetails",
                data:  loginObject,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data != "") {
                        //here I need to create session variables
                        window.location.replace("@Url.Action("Index", "GRN")");
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("username or password is incorrect");
                        window.location.replace("@Url.Action("Login", "GRN")");
                    }
                },

            });
        }


</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`sessionStorage` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

```
sessionStorage.setItem('loggedIn', true);
sessionStorage.getItem('loggedIn'); // true

sessionStorage.removeItem('loggedIn');
sessionStorage.getItem('loggedIn'); // null

// destroy all session storage
sessionStorage.clear();
```

Comment: than how can I destroy session variables with logout

Comment: `sessionStorage.removeItem('loggedIn')`

Comment: I need to destroy all session variables at once, How can I do it??

Comment: can I access these variables any where, I mean out of  script